# Grid widget with proper knockout bindings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, grid, widget, knockout-3.0

I've been looking for the last couple of days for a decent Grid widget with proper knockout bindings; decent grid meaning to have support for filtering, grouping, paging, sorting, aggregates, templates, remote source, etc. Doesn't matter the licence free or commercial. The problem is that all that I found have no/incomplete knockout bindings.

KO support:

- Kendo UI: [incomplete](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html)
- DevExpress: [no support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q471338)
- Wijmo: [most promissing but still incomplete](http://wijmo.com/grid-with-knockout-viewmodel-loading-remote-data/), and example uses the old ko version 2.1
- JQGrid: [poor](https://github.com/CraigCav/Knockout-jqGridBinding/tree/master/src)

I am thinking to go all the distance with knockout meaning that I want to be able to control not only the grid's data source but also the behavior. For instance, one basic feature I am looking for is the ability to control paging (with ko bindings) since my data source can have hundred of thousands of records and I don't want to bring everything on the client.

Do you know any other grid widget that takes ko seriously?

Or do you think I should go for a [custom solution](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html)?

Comment: have you looked at: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid examples here: http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/examples

Comment: Even though KoGrid is discontinued  and incomplete its still the most complete grid there is for KO

Comment: good catch, indeed a grid widget with the most impressive ko integration I've seen so far. It could be a good starting point

Comment: @Tanner, please add your comment as answer so I can accept it

Comment: @alexb have answered with an extended version of my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at KoGrid: [github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid)

If you want some samples of usage check here: [KoGrid Examples](http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/examples)

You just need to data-bind an `observableArray` to `koGrid` and it will take care of the rest.

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObservableArray }"></div>
```

**JS / Knockout**

```
var vm = {
  myObservableArray: ko.observableArray(/* array of any complex obects */)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try TGrid - http://grid.tesseris.com. It's powerful like Telerik or DevExpress and was designed for Knockout.js

Comment: the website you are referring to is empty

Comment: Are you sure? There was a problem with domain name for several days. May be that was the reason of your comment. Now everything is working. Also you can check project page on github.

Comment: Tried to use the files from the sample at this link - got " JavaScript runtime error: 'itemsProvider' is undefined". There's no instruction at all regarding how to connect this stuff at pages in my ASPNET MVC project. Do you know where to place these JS files, and in which sequence?